# i trying to apply crud in django but got this expected string or bytes-like object error

Tags: django, crud

i doing crud operations in django but editing/updateing the user i got an error .
this is my models.py

```
 # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Copyright (c) 2019 - present AppSeed.us
"""

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Member(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 40, blank = False)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    location = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField('%m/%d/%Y')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

this is the views.py file

```
`# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Copyright (c) 2019 - present AppSeed.us
"""

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Member
import datetime
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger


@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def index(request):
    
    context = {}
    context['segment'] = 'index'

    html_template = loader.get_template( 'index.html' )
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def pages(request):
    context = {}
    # All resource paths end in .html.
    # Pick out the html file name from the url. And load that template.
    try:
        
        load_template      = request.path.split('/')[-1]
        context['segment'] = load_template
        
        html_template = loader.get_template( load_template )
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
        
    except template.TemplateDoesNotExist:

        html_template = loader.get_template( 'page-404.html' )
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

    except:
    
        html_template = loader.get_template( 'page-500.html' )
        
@login_required
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        member = Member(
            username=request.POST['username'],
            email = request.POST['email'],
            mobile_number=request.POST['mobile_number'],
            location=request.POST['location'],
            date=request.POST['date'],
            created_at=datetime.datetime.now(),
            updated_at=datetime.datetime.now(), )
        try:
            member.full_clean()
        except ValidationError as e:
            pass
        member.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Member was created successfully!')
        return redirect('/list')
    else:
        return render(request, 'add.html')
    
            
        return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
        
@login_required
def list(request):
    members = Member.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'members': members})

@login_required
def edit(request, id):
    members = Member.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {'members': members}
    return render(request, 'edit.html', context)


@login_required
def update(request, id):
  
    member = Member.objects.get(id=id)
    member.username = request.POST.get('username'),
    member.mobile_number = request.POST.get('mobile_number'),
    member.description = request.POST.get('description'),
    member.location = request.POST.get('location'),
    member.date = request.POST.get('date', False),
    member.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Member was updated successfully!')
    return redirect('/list')
    `
```

this is the urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from app import views
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [

    # The home page
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^create$', views.create, name='create'),
    url(r'^list$', views.list, name='list'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.edit, name='edit'),
    url(r'^edit/update/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.update, name='update'),
    
]
```

this is the edit.html file

```
{% extends 'layout/app.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="content-wrapper">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Breadcrumbs-->
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                    <a href="#">CRUD</a>
                </li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Add</li>
            </ol>
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
                    Crud Add
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="update/{{ members.id }}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-label-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ members.username }}" name="username" placeholder="User Name" id="inputUser" required>
                                    <label for="inputUser">Username</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-label-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ members.email }}" name="email" placeholder="email" id="inputemail" required>
                                    <label for="inputemail">Email</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-label-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="tel" value="{{ members.mobile_number }}" name="mobile_number" placeholder="Mobile Number" id="inputMobile">
                                    <label for="inputMobile">Mobile Number</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-label-group">
                                    <input type="text" id="inputLoca" class="form-control" value="{{ members.location }}"  placeholder="Enter Location" required="">
                                    <label for="inputLoca">Enter Location</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-label-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="date" value="{{ members.date }}" id="dateInput">
                                    <label for="dateInput">Enter Date</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
             
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span></span></button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}

{% endblock %}
```

I have tried very much to overcome this error have applied many solution but can't solve this error.
and the error is:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 27, 2021 - 12:25:24
Django version 2.2.10, using settings 'core.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /edit/update/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/app/views.py", line 95, in update
    member.save()
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 740, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 777, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 850, in _save_table
    updated = self._do_update(base_qs, using, pk_val, values, update_fields,
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 900, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 760, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1462, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1120, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1428, in as_sql
    val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 793, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1279, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1274, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1236, in to_python
    parsed = parse_date(value)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django-dashboard-gradientable/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 74, in parse_date
    match = date_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
[27/Feb/2021 12:25:26] "GET /edit/update/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 139040
```

i don't know what this error means 'unexpected string or bytes-like object'
maybe this error is in date filed but not confirmed.
The error is in update function in i trying to update the user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you print your request.POST and show the results?
Also while updating a model, its probably best for you to use the update method. It is used like below

```
Member.objects.filter(id=id).update(username = request.POST.get('username'),mobile_number = request.POST.get('mobile_number'),description = request.POST.get('description'),location = request.POST.get('location'),date = request.POST.get('date', False))
```

and you dont need to save() it afterwards, update method does it for you.

Comment: I applied your code but i got this error                      raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Comment: Thanks it works i missing the date field when  put date values it start workings

Answer (score 0):

I'd be willing to bet it doesn't like the date you passing in as it likely is coming to you as a string.

You can (read should) eliminate a lot of these issues by using forms, and following the conventional form processing patterns in the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#working-with-forms). Pay particular attention to the suggested pattern for validation in the view (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#the-view).

If you don't want to do that, you can take the date string as posted, then convert it to a datetime object with strptime (see https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-python for a quick how to). The issue you may get is that you are never assured how that date string is going to be passed to you.

You may also wish to review the `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` arguments of the DateTimeField (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield). Much easier way to manage those `created_at` and `updated_at` fields.